# Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.9.0:compile

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, maven, plugins

I have a parent project and three modules one module used the other two as dependencies but I get an error like this when I run `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X`

```
Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.9.0:compile    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doEat org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)215
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)

      NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)oke (
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.throwKotlinCompilerException (MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute (KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute (K2JVMCompileMojo.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the b


no issue related to imports and packaging
```

Comment: Is there more output before that?